# Kubernetes increase resources for all deployments

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, cluster-analysis, kubectl

I am new to Kubernetes. I have a K8 cluster with multiple deployments (more than 150), each having more than 4 pods scaled.
I have a requirement to increase resource limits for all deployments in the cluster; and I'm aware I can increase this directly via my deployment YAML.
However, I'm thinking if there is any way I can increase the resources for all deployments at one go.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can try Vertical Pod Autoscaler with "Auto" mode?

Answer (score 12):

There are few things to point out here:

1. There is a [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch) command that allows you to:

> Update field(s) of a resource using strategic merge patch, a JSON
> merge patch, or a JSON patch.
>
> JSON and YAML formats are accepted.

See examples below:

```
kubectl patch deploy deploy1 deploy2 --type json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/resources/limits/memory", "value":"120Mi"}]'
```

or:

```
kubectl patch deploy $(kubectl get deploy -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{" "}}{{end}}') --type json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/resources/limits/memory", "value":"120Mi"}]'
```

For further reference see [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

2. You can add proper labels into deployment via [kubectl set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-resources-em-) command:

---

```
kubectl set resources deployment -l key=value --limits memory=120Mi
```

3. Also, you can use some additional CLI like `sed`, `awk` or `xargs`. For example:

---

```
kubectl get deployments -o name | sed -e 's/.*\///g' | xargs -I {} kubectl patch deployment {} --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/imagePullPolicy", "value": "Always"}]'
```

or:

```
kubectl get deployments -o name | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs kubectl patch deployment $0  -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

4. It is also worth noting that configuration files should be stored in version control before being pushed to the cluster. See the [Configuration Best Practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kustomize's "components" system if you want to set them all to the same thing. But that's unlikely. Better solution is probably write a little Python (or whatever lang you prefer) script to modify all the YAML files and push them back into source control.